# Can't figure out how to loop through objects in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a grid with different images, the idea was that it would loop through the objects and make the grid, but it is not working at all.

These are the objects:

```
export const Projects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Site 1',
    tech: [
      'HTML',
      'CSS',
      'SASS',
      'React'
    ],
    description: 'Lorem',
    image: './assets/cv.svg'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Site 2',
    tech: [
      'HTML',
      'CSS',
      'SASS',
      'React'
    ],
    description: 'Lorem',
    image: './assets/cv.svg'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Site 3',
    tech: [
      'HTML',
      'CSS',
      'SASS',
      'React'
    ],
    description: 'Lorem',
    image: './assets/cv.svg'
  }
];

export default Projects;
```

This is where I am struggling the most to loop through the objects

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import './Main.scss';
import Projects from '../Projects';
import Item from './Item';

 const Portfolio = ({ Projects }) => {
   const portfolioItem = Projects.map(i => {
     return <Item
     image={Projects[i].image}/>
   })
   return (
     <div>
     {portfolioItem}
     </div>
   )
 }


export default Portfolio;
```

And I am trying to create a single item component here, which will then be used in the previous one

```
import React from 'react';

const Item = ({ image }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={image} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Item;
```

Comment: What is your question? What does "it is not working at all" mean?

Comment: First thing you could try is put another element in the `Item` component to see if the `.map` is working the way you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the map function.

Try:

```
const Portfolio = () => {
  const portfolioItem = Projects.map((project, i) => {
    return <Item
    key={i}
    image={project.image}/>
  })
  return (
    <div>
      {portfolioItem}
    </div>
 )
}
```

The problems I could see were:

1: Importing your static data `Projects`, it doesn't need to be placed 
     into the `props` of your function since it is coming from it's own 
     file. Eventually, if you are getting that information from an API 
     call, you may have need of sending the data to that component through props.

2: In the line for `Projects.map()`, you were trying to access the index of Projects but, the `map` function works a little differently. The first argument is the iterated object and the second is the index.

3: The last part was adding the key prop as React will throw a warning about not having a unique key on iterated items. They all need a unique key so React can determine which children should update depending on the functionality of your iterated items.

Comment: This seemed to work for me, some issues still, that I will try to figure out on my own, but the loop seems to be OK now. Could you please help me understand, what was the issue in my code and why was it not working properly? Much appreciated!

Comment: Added a little explanation. Hopefully that makes sense.